# Does it matter on which phase the solar panel inverter is connected?

Tags: electrical-panel, solar-panels

We have a three phase power supply (3x25A) at our home in The Netherlands (230V). All three phases are used for an induction cooker, and in parallel, two phases (let's call them 1 and 2) each power about half of the household.

We recently had solar panels installed (about 2.5kWp), and the inverter is tied to the third phase (i.e., not 1 or 2, so it is only directly connected to the induction range). Is this the right way to do it? On the one hand, it seems inefficient to draw most power from phase 1 and 2, and supply power to phase 3. On the other hand, the electrical noise from the inverter is all dumped into phase 3 so perhaps it actually isolates the electrical noise from the rest of the household.

Is there a 'right' way to choose which phase the solar panels are connected to? Or does this squarely fall in the **it really doesn't matter** category?

Answer (score 1):

Being a grid-tied installation, it's quite possible that the power utility had some say in which phase to connect the PV system to.  In 3 phase systems, it's necessary to balance the load as equally as possible between the 3 phases but this is difficult to impossible to do within a single household.  So the utility designs the distribution network so that a group of homes share the load across the phases and over a large number, the phases are well balanced.

When connecting PV equipment to their system, generally the utility will provide specific instructions on interconnect based on the capacity and type of your system.  You may not have been aware of this as the installer was likely the one receiving the instruction, not you.

You might check with the installer as to the reasons why they hooked it up as they did.

Comment: Usually the phase connection is load based as my answer suggests.

Comment: @EdBeal But that's only a problem if the transformer sees an unbalanced load, right? America puts like a dozen homes on a transformer, Europe puts more like a hundred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate which phase has the highest average load during the daylight hours and put the system on that. If all your loads were 3 phase (I know they are not) having a single phase solar feed would create imbalances in the system.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why it would be bad to have "imbalances in the system"?

Comment: Imbalances cause problems with transformers I have seen badly balanced systems cause the ground to float by 30v. After balancing the phases there was no float on the ground.  Where I am the code requires the systems to be balanced but doesn’t provide a %. I have seen the imbalance cause problems with computers and ground fault systems.

Comment: The reasons why unbalanced 3 phase loads are troublesome is quite technical and is an entire topic of study in Electrical Engineering.  Power company engineers worry about such things because they wreak havoc on their equipment and also cause troubles for customers.

Comment: Not only power company’s but heavy industry regularly has very large transformers. Electricians balance the loads to prevent problems mentioned above. Not only can an unbalanced load cause a floating ground but the imbalance will cost the consumer. The power companies can easily rebalance the loads as they do. What really costs is when users cause large phase shifts in the power (almost always due to inductive loads) the power company has to adjust if the users do not and this is usually a line item on the bill that can be a significant cost, my last plant we saved 30k/mo with cap banks.